# react native setup error "error Failed to install the app"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

please help me.

I trying to create new project in react native. I ran "npx react-native run-android" and i got this error..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNite.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bXe2.png)

I tryed almost every solution but it's not working.

Comment: Please share the actual error. This is not the exact error.

Answer (score -1):

Please run in terminal:

```
adb devices
```

and check if there is a connected device.

Comment: Please first try to understand the error after that give the solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).